# How can I get enough reputation to get enough reputation?

Tags: discussion

I know that in order to understand recursion one must first understand recursion, but how can I build my reputation enough to post or vote or comment or anything when all these things require reputation to begin with?

Comment: Not like this...

Comment: Ask good questions and give good answers

Comment: You don't need reputation to post a question or an answer, which is the only way to gain reputation.

Comment: or suggest edits.

Comment: Answer: get enough reputation.

Comment: @animuson Yea - i'm sure getting enough reputation will help you get enough reputation to get enough reputation.

Comment: This question title is a paradox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You don't need reputation to post a question or an answer, which is the most common way to gain reputation.**

Here you have information about specific privileges - https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

And here you can read about reputation system - https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to vote to gain reputation. You only need to post good questions and answers; and that requires no reputation at all.

While sometimes voting may be skewed towards the high rep members, usually it isn't and it's just as easy to get rep as a low rep member if you write high quality answers.