# I cannot get started

Tags: support, reputation, newsletter

I am new to Stack Exchange.  Math and physics newsletters get to my inbox every Thursday, and every Thursday there are 5-day-old answers to questions as I read them for the first time.  Too often a question of interest  has already been closed because of the low quality of recent answers and comments.  I have no reputation, and to do almost anything requires more reputation than I have.  Nothing I have found in Help helps (however I noted one user submitted an "answer" because he said he did not have the reputation to comment.  I have started wondering if Joseph Heller is looking over my shoulder.  Any help, please?

Thank you to those who made useful suggestions.  The question, "How does a new user begin using Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?," clearly expressed my difficulties.  I would close the question if I knew how.  Good night.

Comment: Not a duplicate. It's about how to gain initial rep, not about privileges.

Comment: Questions don't get closed because the answers are bad... they get closed because the questions are bad. We'd be a sad site if we closed the difficult questions that got a lot of bad questions... Unless - do you mean the questions are "protected"?

Comment: @S.L.Barth To gain privileges you need to gain reputation, but whether you are seeking privileges or just seeking to gain reputation the advice in that FAQ about how to accumulate early reputation still applies.

Comment: Dup / related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/245360

Comment: If it is a low quality question that is getting low quality answers, edit it to be a high quality question that is on topic, and not too broad (and all those other things).

Comment: Is this about not being able to get started without much rep, or the problem with the newsletters sending you out of date questions? Your question is a bit jumbled. Who is Joseph Heller, and what does he have to do with your question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199852/how-can-i-get-enough-reputation-to-get-enough-reputation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81616/how-should-users-start-earning-reputation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30910/how-do-you-increase-your-stack-overflow-reputation-in-a-realistic-manner

Comment: [Joseph Heller wrote Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Heller)

Comment: "*I would close the question if I knew how*" It already is, see the yellow box in your question with linked dupes, and the yellow info box underneath your question stating the close reason :)

Answer (score 7):

The newsletters are only summaries of interesting question. To start and to earn some reputation you should go to question page of your network site and scroll through it, open question that sound interesting for you by their name and try to answer them to get reputation.

You can also edit posts and earning reputation (up to a maximum of 1000) through it.

Later on you then can do additional things.

Comment: Editing doesn't require any rep, you can do it from the start (and earn rep that way).

Comment: You're right (I edited that), was it mixing up with editing community where you need 100 rep (at least on SO)